# How to terminate and free random number of threads spawned by user?

Tags: delphi

**Scenario:**
User presses Start button random number of times and then has to stop all spawned threads (clicks TerminateButton).

**Question:**
How to correctly terminate/waitfor/free all executed threads by user?

Normally if I had to run specified number of threads I would just use Array of Threads and then cycle .terminate/.waitfor/free for all items in array. 
However in this case I can't do that because number of threads is not determined.

```
procedure TForm1.StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  WorkerThread:=TWorkerThread.Create(true);
  WorkerThread.FreeOnTerminate:=false;
  WorkerThread.Resume;

end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
begin

  repeat
    //some code here
  until Terminated=true;

end;

procedure TForm1.TerminateButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  if Assigned(WorkerThread)=true then // <-This will work only for last instance
  begin
    WorkerThread.terminate;           // <-This will work only for last instance 
    WorkerThread.waitfor;             // <-This will work only for last instance 
    FreeAndNil(WorkerThread);         // <-This will work only for last instance 
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Store them in a list and then free them when needed

Comment: You mean something like TList?

Comment: When you create the threads, add a semaphore. Check the semaphore status in the threads, and when signaled, exit the `Execute` method. (`FreeOnTerminate` shall be set to true)

Comment: "However in this case I can't do that because number of threads is not determined." Well, if you add each one to the array as you create them, then of course the number of threads is determined...

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I'm going to store all threads in TList. This example code seems to work fine.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InitializeCriticalSection(CriticalSection);
  ThreadList:=TList.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DeleteCriticalSection(CriticalSection);
end;

procedure TForm1.StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  EnterCriticalSection(CriticalSection);  //<- This will be required in my real multithreaded code

  WorkerThread:=TWorkerThread.Create(true);
  ThreadList.Add(WorkerThread);
  WorkerThread.FreeOnTerminate:=false;
  WorkerThread.OnTerminate:=form1.ThreadTerminated;
  WorkerThread.Resume;

  LeaveCriticalSection(CriticalSection);

end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
begin

  repeat
    sleep(random(1000));
  until Terminated=true;

end;

procedure TForm1.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('terminated');
end;


procedure TForm1.TerminateButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var x:integer;
begin

  form1.Memo1.Clear;
  EnterCriticalSection(CriticalSection);  //<- This will be required in my real multithreaded code

  for x:=0 to ThreadList.Count-1 do
  begin

    if Assigned(ThreadList.Items[x])=true then
    begin
      WorkerThread:=ThreadList.Items[x];
      WorkerThread.Terminate;
      WorkerThread.waitfor;
      FreeAndNil(WorkerThread);
    end;

  end;

  ThreadList.Clear;

  LeaveCriticalSection(CriticalSection);

end;
```

Comment: Note that you're waiting on your threads consecutively. Depending on the number of threads and how quick they are able to respond this may turn out to be inefficient. In that case read the comments to the question again.

Comment: You should remove the thread reference from when it terminates before you force it, and you should also use what others suggested in comments to the question